# How to upload a video from an Android device, to a server or a host and then retrieve it again?

Tags: android, video, server, video-streaming, streaming

Now am building an android application where i want the user to upload video to the server, then after uploading it, it should appear on the MainActivity, I've set up the login/register using Firebase but Firebase doesn't support streaming Videos(according to my attempts), thus i've been googling for long time about servers and how servers work with video uploading and streaming but i've reached an end point.

What i want to do is, building a system where user can upload a video from his local device, into a server, and then downloading(video streaming from a server), so the user later on can interact with it. I am not sure how to do it, i have searched a lot but couldn't find what i needed to do/learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you upload the video and how you make it available are really two separate questions.

For uploading from Android:

There are a number of libraries you can use to upload to Android - the code below uses the apache multipart client and it is tested and works. Other http libraries include Volley and retrofit.

```js
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class VideoUploadTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer> {
    /* This Class is an AsynchTask to upload a video to a server on a background thread
     * 
     */

    private VideoUploadTaskListener thisTaskListener;
    private String serverURL;
    private String videoPath;

    public VideoUploadTask(VideoUploadTaskListener ourListener) {
        //Constructor
        Log.d("VideoUploadTask","constructor");

        //Set the listener
        thisTaskListener = ourListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Upload the video in the background
        Log.d("VideoUploadTask","doInBackground");

        //Get the Server URL and the local video path from the parameters
        if (params.length == 2) {
            serverURL = params[0];
            videoPath = params[1];
        } else {
            //One or all of the params are not present - log an error and return
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","One or all of the params are not present");
            return -1;
        }


        //Create a new Multipart HTTP request to upload the video
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(serverURL);

        //Create a Multipart entity and add the parts to it
        try {
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","Building the request for file: " + videoPath);
            FileBody filebodyVideo = new FileBody(new File(videoPath));
            StringBody title = new StringBody("Filename:" + videoPath);
            StringBody description = new StringBody("Test Video");
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            reqEntity.addPart("videoFile", filebodyVideo);
            reqEntity.addPart("title", title);
            reqEntity.addPart("description", description);
            httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            //Log the error
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","UnsupportedEncodingException error when setting StringBody for title or description");
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }

        //Send the request to the server
        HttpResponse serverResponse = null;
        try {
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","Sending the Request");
            serverResponse = httpclient.execute( httppost );
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            //Log the error
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","ClientProtocolException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Log the error
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","IOException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Check the response code
        Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","Checking the response code");
        if (serverResponse != null) {
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","ServerRespone" + serverResponse.getStatusLine());
            HttpEntity responseEntity = serverResponse.getEntity( );
            if (responseEntity != null) {
                //log the response code and consume the content
                Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","responseEntity is not null");
                try {
                    responseEntity.consumeContent( );
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //Log the (further...) error...
                    Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","IOexception consuming content");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } 
        } else {
            //Log that response code was null
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","serverResponse = null");
            return -1;
        }

        //Shut down the connection manager
        httpclient.getConnectionManager( ).shutdown( ); 
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        //Check the return code and update the listener
        Log.d("VideoUploadTask onPostExecute","updating listener after execution");
        thisTaskListener.onUploadFinished(result);
    }
```

To make the video available on the server side you just need a HTTP server that can server static content or a video streaming server - the latter will allow you use Adaptive Bit Rate Streaming (ABR - e.g. HLS or DASH) for better quality, but may be overkill for your needs.

Either approach will provide you withe a URL for the video which you can use an Android player like ExoPlayer to play back the video with:

- https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer